# How can I transform the result of a stored procedure into xml on the sql server? 

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that can NOT be modified, the result of this stored procedure is normal select statement as following :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LockedProcedure
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM COLORS_TABLE
END
```

my problem is that I need to get its result as XML result like how the select statement returns when you provide "FOR XML" but without modifying the procedure itself, maybe we can create another stored procedure to call that or user defined function.

This is an example of the procedure that we CAN NOT modify because it is locked.

how to get its result as XML result NOT XML FILE...I don't want any physical file on hard disk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1)**

1. Create a temp table matching the output definition of stored procedure.
2. Use `INSERT INTO #Tmp EXEC SPName` to insert the stored procedure results into the temp table.
3. Use `FOR XML` in combination with `SELECT` command to fetch the results as xml from temp table.

**Solution 2)**

Create a CLR User-Defined function to execute the stored procedure and use the BCL facilities to convert the results to xml.

Comment: I have more than one procedure and the definition of the stored procedure is not static so i can not make sure that i can follow the temp table solution because every time i call the procedure it gives me different definition...also i can not use CLR

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this but in my case editing the stored procedure is possible.  Even though the OP mentions the stored procedure is locked, I still wanted to post this solution here for others that stumble upon it. This solution assumes the stored procedure uses dynamic SQL to select some data, but could just as easily be adapted to a non-dynamic SQL case.

1. Add a parameter to the sp such as "@lp_ReturnAsXML      BIT = 0".  When set to true, you will return the result set as XML using "FOR XML RAW" or some similar command.
2. Then add this to the end of the stored procedure as an alternative for running the dynamic SQL:

   ```
   IF @lp_ReturnAsXML = 1
   BEGIN
       DECLARE @l_XML XML
       SET @l_SQL = 'SET @l_XML = (SELECT * FROM ( ' +
           @l_SQL + '
           ) d FOR XML RAW)'
       EXEC sp_executesql @l_SQL, N'@l_XML XML OUTPUT', @l_XML = @l_XML OUTPUT
       SELECT @l_XML
   END
   ```

Now something like this should work:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    Results XML
)

INSERT INTO @table
EXEC p_MyStoredProc ..., @lp_ReturnAsXML = 1
```